# consolidate Array multiple sheets

Tags: arrays, vba, worksheet-function

please advise how can i get to Dim sheets as at times there can be more than 300 sheets and not every sheet will have sheet name as (sheet4). i would have to consolidate the same array R10C1:R26C2

```
Sub Macro15()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim arrRange()

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

arrRange = Array("Sheet4!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (2)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (3)!R10C1:R26C2", _
"Sheet4 (4)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (5)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (6)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (7)!R10C1:R26C2", _
"Sheet4 (8)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (9)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (10)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (11)!R10C1:R26C2", _
"Sheet4 (12)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (13)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (14)!R10C1:R26C2")

Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add

With ws2
    .Range("A1").Consolidate arrRange, xlSum, True, True, False
End With

Application.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-228
ws.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 23.88
ws.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 41.25
ws.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 47.88
ws.Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 16.5

End Sub
```

Comment: Make a loop through all sheets, within loop, refer to sheet by index, concatenate sheet name and the range, and put in array.

Comment: @omegastripes please could you give an example it would be really helpful I have very basic skills with vba

Answer (score 0):

Not tested : But you could try something like this to get the sheet names and and concatenate the range to it when the sheet name is copied into the array.

```
Dim sheets_Count As Integer
Dim sheets_Name() As String

sheets_Count = Sheets.Count

ReDim sheets_Name(sheets_Count)

For i = 1 To sheets_Count
    sheets_Name(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next i

end sub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: please can you guide me on how to concatenate the range to it when the sheet name is copied into the array. regards.

Comment: Hi, 

You can perform a concatenation when the sheetname is copied into the array as follows :

    sheets_Name(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & " R10C1:R26C2"

Comment: Option Explicit
Sub Macro22()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim arrRange()
Dim sheets_Count As Integer
Dim sheets_Name() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrayrange

sheets_Count = Sheets.Count
ReDim sheets_Name(sheets_Count)
For i = 1 To sheets_Count
   sheets_Name(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next i

arrayrange = [R10C1:R26C2]

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

arrRange = Array("sheets_Name(i)!arrayrange")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add
With ws2
    .Range("A1").Consolidate arrRange, xlSum, True, True, False
End With
End Sub

Comment: i have put that now but it gives me error saying cannot open consolidation source file 'sheets_names(i)' although i have sheets open in active workbook with sheets name sheet4,sheet4(1), sheet8, sheet 9 etc